# Angular reactive form element set array field with array data

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using `Angular 6` and `Reactive form` to build a form.

In the `ngOnInit()` function, I have intialized a form group like

```
this.landingPageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required
  ]),
  images: this.formBuilder.array([])
});
```

In this form group, I want `images` to be a hidden input field because values will be inserted from the component. and `title` will be displayed to the user.

I have a array variable that hold url to the images.

```
images: Array = [];

console.log(images);
```

consoling `images` gives data in following format

```
[
    "https://example.com/image1.jpg", 
    "https://example.com/image2.jpg", 
    "https://example.com/image3.jpg"
]
```

to set the value of `images` into `images` input field. I'm trying

```
this.landingPageForm.setValue({
    title: this.product.info.title,
    images: this.images || [],
});
```

But it gives error as

```
There are no form controls registered with this array yet.  If you're using ngModel,
    you may want to check next tick (e.g. use setTimeout).
```

I tried with inserting a hidden input field for images like

```
<input type="hidden" formControlName="images">
and
<input type="hidden" formControlName="images[]">
```

But still, the same error is there.

**How can I set the values of `images` variable in the array input field?**

Comment: Try to create a new `formContol` for each of the image urls in the `images` array. Then push those `formControl`s in to images  `formArray`

Answer (score 0):

I have three points on your snippet:

- You are not associating your `Form Fields` with `Form Control` as the error says.
- Also, I guess you are missing the association with the `FormName` in your html.  Or maybe you haven't added that line here.
- Also you don't need to insantiate the `FormGroup` in `NgOnInit()`. You can simple assign the value during the `NgOnInit()`.

Make use of the snippet below for your typescript:

```
export class FormFieldOverviewExample implements OnInit{
   constructor(private formBuilder : FormBuilder){}
   images: any[];
   product:any;

   //Assign FormControl to the fields
   landingPageForm = new FormGroup({
       title: new FormControl(''),
       images: new FormControl(''),
   });

   ngOnInit(){
       images: any[] = [
           "https://example.com/image1.jpg", 
           "https://example.com/image2.jpg", 
           "https://example.com/image3.jpg"
       ];
       product = {"info":{"title" : "Product Title"}};
       this.landingPageForm.setValue({
       title: this.product.info.title,
       images: this.images || [],
       });
   }
```

The html snippet:

```
<form [formGroup]="landingPageForm">
<input formControlName="images">
</form>
```